# What does this Powershell line do?

Tags: powershell

I want to understand what this PowerShell line means, so I could write it in C#?

```
$visitor = $roles | ? { `
    ($groups | ? { $_.Title -like '*Visitors'} | % {$_.Id}) -Contains `
    $_.PrincipalId } | select -ExpandProperty PrincipalId
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$Visitor` is a variable that the end result of this code will be stored in.

`$Roles` must already contain some set of infomation from earlier in the script

`? { ($groups | ? { $_.Title -like '*Visitors'}`

? { } is a way of using the `Where-object` function. So this code is grabbing and objects with the "Title" property inside of `$groups` that contains the text "Visitors"

`| % {$_.Id}) -Contains $_.PrincipalId }`

This part is taking the results of the previous code, and saying for every object returned it will look for the "PrincipalID" property and see if it exists in the "Id" property

`| select -ExpandProperty PrincipalId`

if the previous code returns objects, it sends them to this code which selects the property "PrincipalId" and that is what is stored into the `$Visitor` variable.

If any of my thoughts are incorrect please someone let me know so I can edit this, I tried with what knowledge I have.